# What is "plurisecular"? Can't find this word's meaning, only translations

Tags: meaning, word-usage, translation, neologisms

Here's a quote from Robert Hurley's translation of Michel Foucault's *History of Sexuality* arguing for the historical importance of the anonymous author of *My Secret Life*:

> ...he was the most direct and in a way the most naïve representative of a **plurisecular** injunction to talk about sex.

I've been searching for this word on Google, but it's giving me only translations, not an explanation, and I don't know the languages it provides me translations for.

Does anybody know what this word means?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108487/discussion-on-question-by-p-vowk-what-is-plurisecular-cant-find-this-words).

Comment: Given in Wiktionary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short, it means **centuries-old** or **age-old**.

It's formed from the prefix *pluri* and the word *secular*.

Both from Merriam-Webster.

[**pluri-**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pluri-):

> : many : having or being more than one : MULTI-
>   // *pluri*axial [having more than one axis]
>   // *pluri*locular [divided into chambers]

[**secular**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secular):

> **3 a** : occurring once in an age or a century
>   **3 b** : existing or continuing through ages or centuries
>   **3 c** : of or relating to a long term of indefinite duration
>           // *secular* inflation

*Secular* has other senses, mostly related to things that are of the material world, or not religious, but in the sense used for this combined word it's this one.

From [a translation by Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/spanish-english/translation/plurisecular.html) between Spanish and English (emphasis mine):

> [...] le competen las tareas y los honores que por antigua tradición y Estatuto se
>   reconocen a esta **plurisecular** magistratura.
>
> [...] and is vested with the rights and honours to which this **centuries-old** magistracy is entitled to by tradition and under the Charter.

Comment: The folks at Larousse (a leading French dictionary publisher) [define *pluriséculaire* to mean](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/pluriséculaire/61808) "qui s'étend sur plusieurs siècles": "extending over several centuries."  Given that Foucault was writing in French, this is almost certainly what he meant.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert isn't it almost the same?

Comment: @P.Vowk: Yes; it is — I think MichaelSeifert is mentioning that (highly relevant) point as as confirmation/corroboration of the answer.

Comment: "age-old injunction" seems like such a natural translation; I wonder why the translator didn't just use that.

Comment: @P.Vowk:  Yes, I simply meant to point out that an equivalent word exists with the same meaning in the quote's original language.

Comment: This is indeed the correct answer to the question of what *plurisecular* means in this text, but it should be noted that it is a very awkward word to use as the translation of *pluriséculaire*. While *secular* in English does have this meaning, it is a rarely used one, and far down the lists of its meanings that appear in dictionaries; in French, on the other hand, it is the primary meaning of *séculaire*. An English speaker thus needs to pause and think about what *plurisecular* means, while a French speaker understands *pluriséculaire* right away.

Comment: @jsw29 I suppose, people will be coming here all the time to check the meaning. As there already is such a translation, it's good to have this explanation here for people not to get lost. My opinion.

Comment: Compounding is not guaranteeably productive. Have you supporting evidence that _plurisecular_ is in the English lexicon? A single dictionary entry?

Answer (score 10):

The prefix "pluri-" means "many", and "secular" comes from Latin and means "century". Therefore, "plurisecular" would mean "extending over several/many centuries".

[Definition of "secular"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/secular):

3a: occurring once in an age or a century

b: existing or continuing through ages or centuries

c: of or relating to a long term of indefinite duration
- *secular inflation*

Comment: Given that this is in a translation from a text in French, this looks plausible.

Comment: http://latindictionary.wikidot.com/noun:saeculum

Comment: I'm still not sure which answer is better, actually. I'll look at it once again once I get more time to reflect on the  matter. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @P.Vowk You're welcome. I'm happy with my score of 9, so thanks anyway.

Comment: ' "Plurisecular" _would_ mean ....' Not _does_? Compounding is not guaranteeably productive. Have you supporting evidence that _plurisecular_ is in the English lexicon? A single dictionary entry?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You don't need to find all compound words in the dictionary -- if the compounding mechanism is valid, so will the compound word be in all likelihood. Checking Google books, you will find several good examples of "plurisecular". That seems enough evidence to me.

Comment: But an answer claiming wordness for a candidate is inadequate if it does not show _reasonable_ supporting evidence. And when the word is actually _given_ in some dictionaries, the inadequacy is clear.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth When does a word start to exist? When the authors of a dictionary decide to include it, or when highly educated native speakers start to use it? I think it might be the latter, in keeping with the dynamic nature of language development.

Comment: But on ELU, as with all SE sites, a reasonable level of corroboration is expected. Inclusion in a recognised dictionary (and Wiktionary, although quicker to recognise candidates than some others, is a reasonable resource) is better than a few examples of perhaps novel jargon. And certainly light years ahead of the lack of any reference displayed in this answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Light years ahead? Isn't it too much? Corroboration in the form of well-written texts is a more than reasonable level of confirmation. If you don't agree, you can downvote my answer as well as Jason Bassford's if you wish.

Comment: My comments to both were courtesies.

Answer (score 3):

This is, in fact, [in Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plurisecular#English):

> *(rare, academic)* Of or related to a span of several centuries, centuries-old.